# Creating functions in Matlab

Tags: matlab, function, matrix, indexing

[image: Question]

---

Hi, I am trying to write a function as per the question. I have tried to create four sub-matrices which are the reverse of each other and then multiply to give the products demanded by the question. My attempt:

```
function T = custom_blocksT(n,m)
    T(1:end,end-1:1);
    T(1:end,end:-1:1)*2;
    T(1:end,end:-1:1)*3;
    T(1:end,end:-1:1)*4;
```

What I'm unsure of is

(i) What do the the indivual sub-matrices`(T(1:end,end-1:1);)`need to be equal to? I was thinking of`(1:3)`?

(ii) I tried to create a generic sub-matrix which can take any size matrix input using end was this correct or can't you do that? I keep getting this error

`Undefined function or variable 'T'.`

`Error in custom_blocksT (line 2)`
`T(1:end,end-1:1);`

I have searched the Matlab documentation and stacked overflow, but the problem is I'm not quite sure what I'm supposed to be looking for in terms of solving this question.

If someone could help me I would be very thankfull.

Comment: There are so many wrong things.... Your function shoudl get a matrix, not 2 values. `T(1:end,end-1:1)` makes no sense because 1)T doesnt exist yet, 2)you are not making an assigment. There are too many things wrong for us to be able to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many problems with your function:

```
function T = custom_blocksT(n,m)
    T(1:end,end-1:1);
    T(1:end,end:-1:1)*2;
    T(1:end,end:-1:1)*3;
    T(1:end,end:-1:1)*4;
end
```

This is an extremely basic question, I highly recommend you find and work through some very basic MATLAB tutorials before continuing, even before reading this answer to be honest.

That said here is what you should have done and a bit of what you did wrong:

First, you are getting the error that `T` dos not exist because it doesn't. The only variables that exist in your function are those that you create in the function or those that are passed in as parameters. You should have passed in `T` as a parameter, but instead you passed in `n` and `m` which you don't use.

In the question, they call the function using the example:

```
custom_blocks([1:3;3:-1:1])
```

So you can see that they are only passing in one variable, your function takes two and that's already a problem. The one variable is the matrix, not it's dimensions. And the matrix they are passing in is `[1:3;3:-1:1]` which if you type in the command line you will see gives you

```
[1   2   3
 3   2   1]
```

So for your first line to take in one argument which is that matrix it should rather read

```
function TOut = custom_blocks(TIn)
```

Now what they are asking you to do is create a matrix, `TOut`, which is just different multiples of `TIn` concatenated.

What you've done with say `TIn(1:end,end-1:1)*2;` is just ask MATLAB to multiple `TIn` by `2` (that's the only correct bit) but then do nothing with it. Furthermore, indexing the rows by `1:end` will do what you want (i.e. request all the rows) but in MATLAB you can actually just use `:` for that. Indexing the columns by `end-1:1` will also call all the columns, but in reverse order. So in effect you are flipping your matrix left-to-right which I'm sure is not what you wanted. So you could have just written `TIn(:,:)` but since that's just requesting the entire matrix unchanged you could actually just write `TIn`.

So now to multiply and concatenate (i.e. stick together) you do this

```
TOut = [TIn, TIn*2; TIn*3, TIn*4]
```

The `[]` is like a concatenate operation where `,` is for horizontal and `;` is for vertical concatenation.

Putting it all together:

```
function TOut = custom_blocks(TIn)
    TOut = [TIn, TIn*2; TIn*3, TIn*4];
end
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your response, I'm going to take your advice and go through some tutorials and try and improve my knowledge before attempting more questions! I have a couple of books (Attaway and Gilat) and also the Matlab programming fundamentals guide, is there better places to find this information or will these materials be OK?

Comment: Don't know, a programming fundamentals guide sounds like a good place to start though. Give it a go, revisit this question and make sure you understand everything that was said. It's all basic, you need to know it all if you want to work with MATLAB

Comment: OK, thanks for your advice, I'll go through the fundamentals guide and try and make sense of what the question requires and how to apply this to other functions.